# When is a member object constructed when initialized in the constructor's initialization list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, default-constructor

If a member object `data` does **not** appear in the constructor's initialization list, then `data` is constructed by its default constructor.

If `data` **appears** in the constructor's initialization list, then it is simply *initialized* to the given value. Does this imply that there is no constructor call for creating `data`? How is the new object `data` constructed then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If data appears in the constructor's initialization list, then it is simply initialized to the given value.

No, it is initialised using whatever arguments are supplied. If it has a class type, then the arguments are passed to a suitable constructor.

> Does this imply that there is no constructor call for creating data?

No. If it has a class type, then initialisation is done by calling a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you're initializating `data` in the constructor's initialization list, its parametrized constructor is called.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Data {
public:
    Data(int firstArg, std::string mSecondArg)
    {
        std::cout<<"parameterized constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(int firstArg, std::string secondArg) : data(firstArg, secondArg) {}
private:
    Data data;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass(0, new std::string("empty"));
    return 0;
}
```

With this code you will get output
`parameterized constructor called`

Answer (score 0):

> **§12.6.2/7:** The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the initialization rules of **8.5** for direct-initialization.

Which, in other words, means the normal constructor is called.

For example:

```
class Foo { Bar bar; Foo () : bar(...) { } };
```

is analoguous to creating `Bar` object as such:

```
Bar bar (...);
```